# obtener todos los datos de una tabla sql y asignarlos a un objeto c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buen día, tengo una objeto inicializado y vacío, que hereda de mi modelo Software este objeto me servirá para hacer un recorrido y dependiendo de una condición x asignara como seleccionado o no seleccionado un atributo nuevo

quisiera saber como puedo llenar mi objeto con la información ya existente en mi tabla de B, para poder hacer este recorrido

clase:

```
 public class Sistemas : Eq_tblSoftware
        {
            public string Seleccionado { get; set; }
        }
```

funcion:

```
     public JsonResult GetSoftware(int id)
            {
    
                Sistemas sistemas = new Sistemas();
    
          Sistemas sistemas = new Sistemas();
               
//llenado de datos 
     }
```

Comment: Puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: Quisiera hacer que sistemas contenga toda la información de mi tabla software de mi bd pero acabo de caer en cuenta que sistemas debe ser un lista para poder hacer eso

Comment: Usas entityframework?

Comment: si, estoy usando Entity Framework y estoy en ASP.net mvc

Comment: Si usas entityframework no tienes que preocuparte por cargar los datos, ya que te liberas de esto

Comment: Disculpa puedes ser mas especifico?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132001/discussion-between-japv-and-oscar).